# Linked Arithmetic progression and Harmonic progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like to give some introduction about the origin of my doubt and then put forth my doubt , so that people who attempt answering will know the context .

```
 Introduction :
```

In general as speed is inversely proportional to time . Given that the distance is constant , when the velocities are in AP , the corresponding times will be in HP .Similarly when velocities are in HP , the corresponding times will be in AP .

So for the following data ,

Person's velocity if 10 km/hr  he reaches at  1  p.m.

Person's velocity if 15 km/hr  he reaches at  11 a.m.

So for him to reach at noon what should be his speed ?

so times here are in AP 11 a.m , 12 , 1 p.m with common difference of 1 hr . so velocities will be in HP .

Speed required to reach at noon  = Harmonic mean of 10 and 15 = 12 .
So if he drives at 12 km/hr he will reach by noon . Following this method saves energy and time spent in solving this problem via equations with many unknowns .

```
 Problem situation :
```

In a similar fashion I want to solve the following problem

A person travels from his home to office at 4km/hr and reaches there 20 min late.If he goes at 6 km/hr he reaches 10 min early.what is the speed required to reach on time at his office?

so the 2 series under consideration are

4km/hr    ,    6km/hr   and

+20min    ,    -10min

Here I will not definitely be able to find it as Arithmetic mean or Harmonic mean . So my question is by moving the time series 10 minutes up  , will I be able to find the magnitude by which I should change the velocity series . If I am able to  change the AP (or HP)  and see the effect it has on the other series HP (or AP) , I can solve this in no time . Because my aim is to add 10 to time series so that the -10 will become 0 minutes (as 0 minutes delay means he is in time ) and if I know the impact it has on velocity series, I can change the velocity 6 accordingly and that will be my answer .

Note: This problem can be solved using equations of speed , time ,distance . But the motive behind using this approach is to avoid equations .Example problem avoids equations and also it is solved .

Thanks

Comment: Playing with the numbers may not get you there; algebra certainly will. Let $d$ be the distance, home to office; let $x$ be the required speed, and $t$ the time it takes when travelling at that speed; set up some equations, and solve them.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I am searching methods to solve speed distance time problems without equations or less equations.And this AP and HP idea prescribed in many books seems to quell my thirst .So I wanted to apply this in this problem as well.  I have given a example where I solved without equations .

Comment: Understood, but I bet the way someone invented the AP/HP method in the other kind of problem was by using algebra to solve it and then seeing the progressions. I suspect that's the only way to find the manipulations that are going to work for this problem.

Comment: Sorry . I did not get your point "I suspect that's the only way to find the manipulations that are going to work for this problem."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your AP and HP with four terms
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
\mathrm{AP} & -10 & 0 & +10 & +20 \\
\hline
\mathrm{HP} & 6=a & x=\frac{a}{1+d} & \frac{a}{1+2d} & 4 = \frac{a}{1+3d}
\end{array}
$$
then $d=1/6$ and $x=36/7$.

Comment: Thank you very much .Amazing way to solve . This was what I was searching for . No equations . Just playing with numbers to solve the problem . Your solution does it . Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your on-time speed directly from the two data points by using a (sort of) weighted HM:

$$v = \frac{20-(-10)}{\displaystyle \frac{20}{6} - \frac{-10}{4}} = \frac{36}{7}\, \text{km}/\text{hr}$$

This answer makes no assumptions about the nature of the relations between the speeds.  It merely uses the fact that the distance to work is the same in all cases.

(Truth be told, I did use a bit of algebra to come up with the expression, but the result is very straightforward.)

**ADDENDUM**

At the risk of alienating the OP, here is what I did to arrive at the answer above.

Let $v_1=4 \,\text{km}/\text{hr}$, $v_2=6 \,\text{km}/\text{hr}$, $\Delta_1 = 20 \, \text{min}$, $\Delta_2 = -10\, \text{min}$.  Also let $T$ be the time it should take to get to work on time.  The statement that the distance to work is the same in any case is

$$v_1 (T+\Delta_1) = v_2 (T+\Delta_2)$$

which means that

$$T = \frac{v_2 \Delta_2 - v_1 \Delta_1}{v_1-v_2}$$

Now let $v$ be the speed at which one gets to work on time.  Using the fact that the distance to work is also $v T$, we get

$$\begin{align}v T = v_1 (T+\Delta_1) \implies v &= v_1 \left ( 1 + \frac{\Delta_1}{T}\right )\\ &= v_1 \left ( 1 + \frac{\Delta_1 (v_1-v_2)}{v_2 \Delta_2 - v_1 \Delta_1}\right ) \\ &= v_1 \frac{v_2 \Delta_2 - v_1 \Delta_1 + v_1 \Delta_1 - v_2 \Delta_1}{v_2 \Delta_2 - v_1 \Delta_1} \\ &= v_1 v_2 \frac{\Delta_2-\Delta_1}{v_2 \Delta_2 - v_1 \Delta_1} \end{align}$$

or,

$$v = \frac{\Delta_1-\Delta_2}{\displaystyle \frac{\Delta_1}{v_2} - \frac{\Delta_2}{v_1}}$$

Comment: Have a talk with @Zander, who says the answer is $36/7$. See whether you two can come to some agreement.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: no need to.  Zander's answer comes from an assumption that the speeds follow a certain harmonic progression.  This is inexact and there really is no physical basis for it.  My result comes from actually computing the distance and working backward to get the speed needed to get to work on time.  That probably violates the "no equation" edict, but my result is exact and simply stated.

Comment: I get 6 km for the distance (1 hour at 6 km/hr, 1 hr 30 min at 4 km/hr). You want to do the 6 km in 1 hr 10 min, which comes to $36/7$ km/hr.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I made a transposition error in plugging the numbers in my formula.  $36/7$ is indeed correct.

Comment: So, presumably Zander's reasoning is correct.

Comment: Hi Ron , can you please clarify the statement "we get, after some algebra:" a bit elaborately and tell what is the algebra which led to that formula .

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Presumably, although it is a bit opaque to me.

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam: see edit

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Hi , Thanks for the effort put in the derivation . This definitely helps .As far as solving using equations are concerned there are a number of easier ways .I posted this question to get answer just by number manipulation . Zander's answer helps from that point of view .Any way thank you very much for the final derived formula .

Comment: @GerryMyerson : In comment 2 you have said the following "Zander's answer comes from an assumption that the speeds follow a certain harmonic progression. This is inexact and there really is no physical basis for it " . Zander chose times to be in AP .So naturally speeds will be in HP .Please may I know what is wrong in that ?

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam: please address me and not Gerry.  Anyway, I may have jumped the gun with the word 'inexact', although I do not understand why the speeds must follow such a sequence.

Comment: It was a miss. sorry Ron .